# How to fix gradle build problems on Android Studio 4 while importing projects?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a newbie in Android Studio. Currently, I am using Android Studio 4. While importing a project built on an older version ([Github Link of the project](https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/tree/Starter-code)), the gradle sync fails. The following error shows up:

Gradle sync failed: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip'.
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (13 s 167 ms)

I have tried many ways to fix the issue but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update gradle version.

1. Open https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/blob/lesson-one/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and change version from 2.10 to 6.7.
2. Open https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/blob/lesson-one/build.gradle#L8 and change plugin version from 2.1.0 to 4.1.0.
3. Make sure you use Android studio 4.1.0+.

Comment: The following error is shown after updating the gradle version:

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: @SohanKundu I've updated the answer, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is to update your gradle from File->project structure->project to the latest version, before resync remember to clean project and sync again if problem still exist look for your classpath in gradle project level and make sure it is equal to the project classpath.